# Why are different cases used in change logs?

Tags: grammar

Many *change logs* read like this:

> Notable changes in this release include:
>
> ```
> Allow screen-reader to read relationship attributes in nested elements.
> Ensure all binaries are securely signed and linked with the hardened runtime in the macOS bundle.
> Added support to view multilevel partitioned tables.
> Rename some internal environment variables that could conflict with Kubernetes.
> Fix an issue where operator, access method and operator class is not visible for exclusion constraints.
> Ensure that constraints, indexes, rules, triggers, and compound triggers should be created on partitions.
> Fix syntax highlighting in code mirror for backslash and escape constant.
> Ensure that the user should be able to select/modify tablespace for the partitioned table on v12 and above.
> Added support for on-demand loading of items in Select2
> ```

Notice the inconsistent used of *allow* versus *ensured*, etc. Does this serve a purpose? Or is this inconsistency just accepted in the community.

Comment: What is a FOSS developer?

Comment: You are asking why programmers are not writers. That's how I get my work as a technical writer, working carefully with left-brain subject matter experts. But verbs like allow and ensure are not future tense - they are the imperatives given to the programmer as checklists: Allow this screen function, Ensure that securing. Programmers are merely copying their to-do lists into the internal logs. Editors are not reading them, only coders do - and their standards are not  demanding.

Comment: Have you considered a language barrier? FOSS does not mean only English speaking.

Comment: Seems fairly normal to me.

Comment: "I like traditions if they are sensible" - I would argue that in this case, the tradition, which might not be sensible, would be to always write with consistent and correct grammar. The point of language is communication and grammatical consistency often helps us communicate more effectively.  But not always.  In these cases, there's really no ambiguity to the meanings of the messages - the tense or mood just doesn't matter. So, if everyone understands the message, whatever it's tense/mood, why bother worrying about choosing the right, or even the same one?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's subjective,  leading,  and not really about English.

Comment: I've made substantial edits to remove anything irrelevant (and often inflammatory).

Comment: It’s unclear why using different words is a problem in this context.

Comment: The word "ensured" does not appear anywhere in the change log. When I'm in charge of commit messages, I follow the **style** that the first word must be an imperative verb. You can find well written articles on this subject which explain this **opinion**. However, this isn't an English question, but a **documentation style** question.

Answer (score 4):

This isn't really about English, but I'll answer it since there is an answer. This will be purely about the correctness of the English, not the merits of each approach from a software development point of view.

The reason you are seeing these two kinds of summaries is that different developers consider the summaries to be the answers to two different questions.

One group considers the summaries to describe **what the purpose of the changes is**. So they are implicitly writing:

> [The purpose of this change is to] Allow [the] screen-reader to read relationship attributes in nested elements.

The other group considers the summaries to **describe what they did in the change.** They are implicitly writing:

> [In this change I] Added support for on-demand loading of items in Select2

Since neither is a complete sentence, neither can be considered "correct" from a grammatical point of view. Neither are "lazy" or "weird". There are advantages to consistency, but whether enforcing one style or the other is worth the hassle is up to the team making the changes. And any debate about it definitely belongs on a software engineering site, not a language usage site.

Comment: Different developers, or developers in different moods.  I am consistently inconsistent in my commit messages.

Answer (score 0):

FOSS = Free/Open Source Software.

*Change logs* show modifications to the software.

People don't always get these comments right, but they should try.

> `Allow screen-reader to read relationship attributes in nested elements.`

This describes the modification from the software's perspective.

> `Added support to view multilevel partitioned tables.`

This describes the modification from the developer's perspective.

> `Ensure all binaries are securely signed and linked with the hardened runtime in the macOS bundle.`

This is a great example of why this can matter. Who is doing the ensuring? As written, this tells me that the developer built a feature that will "[e]nsure all binaries...".  Changing this to *ensured* would mean the developer did something to the existing binaries.

Now let's say a new binary comes along. As written, something would happen if the binary wasn't securely signed and linked. Maybe it's an immediate failure, and possibly it's automation of the signing/linking.

In the *ensured* case, nothing would happen to the new binary. The developer would need to do whatever they did before again. By the sounds of it, maybe this is a potential security hole that a developer "ensured" something at this moment in time, but that the software can not "ensure" this going forward. In the "ensured" case, it conceivable that every developer on the project would need to know about the process and address this issue. That's difficult to enforce and plan for.

This doesn't always matter, but when it does, it can matter a lot.

Comment: I don't think the difference is as clear cut in your example as you indicate.

Answer (score 0):

The text that shows up in the changelog is the one-line subject from each commit message.

In a well-known (among FOSS developers) blog post, Chris Beams describes [how to write a good commit message](https://chris.beams.io/posts/git-commit/). After explaining why a good commit message matters, he lays out seven rules for writing one. Rule number five is "Use the imperative mood in the subject line," which he claims "follow[s] Git’s own built-in conventions."

Beams gives the example of a changelog when these rules are followed:

> - Refactor subsystem X for readability
> - Update getting started documentation
> - Remove deprecated methods
> - Release version 1.0.0

And an example when the rules are ignored:

> - Fixed bug with Y
> - Changing behavior of X
> - More fixes for broken stuff
> - Sweet new API methods

If the rules are followed, the resulting changelog is more readable.